# Criar lista ordenada por letra com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Como posso criar uma lista ordenada pela letra inicial usando AngularJS? Eu tenho várias categorias em um arquivo json e gostaria de listá-las por blocos com as inicias.

Blocos ordenados assim:

**A**

Academia

Animais

**B**

Bares

Beleza e Estética

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma simples função de agrupamento em *vanilla JS* pode solucionar seu problema.

No exemplo de implementação a seguir um objeto (`grp`) é criado, contendo a seguinte estrutura:

```
{
  "A": [
    "Academia",
    "Animais"
  ],
  "B": [
    "Bares",
    "Beleza e Estética"
  ]
}
```

Clique em <kbd>Executar Trecho de Código</kbd> para ver o resultado:

```js
(function () {
  var app = angular.module('store', []);
  app.controller('sampleController', function ($scope) {

    var json = ["Academia","Animais","Bares","Beleza e Estética"];

    var grp = {}; // Inicializando o objeto.

    var result = json.forEach(function(item) {
      var chr = item.charAt(0);  // Obtendo o primeiro caracter
      if (!grp.hasOwnProperty(chr)) grp[chr] = []; // Se não existe grupo para 
                                                   // o caracter, crie e inicialize
      grp[chr].push(item); // Adicione item ao grupo
    });
    
    $scope.grp = grp;
  });
})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="store">
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-controller="sampleController">

      <div ng-repeat='(k,v) in grp'>
        <h2>{{k}}</h2>
        
        <div ng-repeat="i in v">
          <h4>{{i}}</h4>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Até consegui fazer algo mais simples aqui, só que quando tentei passar pro Angular não deu muito certo, ainda estou estudando e com um pouco de dificuldade ^^

Comment: @AltembergAndrade É sempre um prazer ajudar, fico feliz que tenha funcionado pra você. =)

Comment: uma das categorias é a de Áudio e acabou criando um bloco novo. Como faço para que ela seja incluída também no bloco da letra A?